# Running tests with pytest for cli tool written in python using poetry

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am following the [coding challenge of building a json parser in Python](https://codingchallenges.fyi/challenges/challenge-json-parser) as an *exercise* and I built my solution using `poetry` to manage the project and wanted to run the tests using `pytest`. However, I wanted to be as rigorous as possible and wanted to test the cli produced by `poetry` using some files I have under `./tests` folder.

The cli is defined in poetry as

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
pyccjsonparser = "pyccjsonparser.main:_cli"
```

So far I am doing:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "file,exit_code",
    [
        (Path("doesnt-exist.extension"), 1),
        (Path(".").absolute().parent / "tests" / "step1" / "valid.json", 0),
        (Path(".").absolute().parent / "tests" / "step1" / "invalid.json", 2),
    ],
)
def test(file: Path, exit_code: int):
    proc = subprocess.run(
        ["pyccjsonparser", f"{file}"],
        executable=sys.executable,
        capture_output=True,
        text=True,
    )
    assert proc.returncode == exit_code, proc.stderr + proc.stdout
```

I have been unable to make it work for a while, I found the relation between `cwd` and the paths to the script and the test files to be quite complex. My current error is that the return code doesn't match what is expected (and I know it works, because I have unittests for it). I get the following assertion error:

```
E       AssertionError: 
E       assert 0 == 2
E        +  where 0 = CompletedProcess(args=['pyccjsonparser', '{path}/codingchallenges_solutions/json_parser/tests/step1/invalid.json'], returncode=0, stdout='', stderr='').returncode
```

(note that I have hidden my actual path from the assertion error, but it is fine)

Here is the full code if anyone wants to have a look: https://github.com/srcolinas/codingchallenges_solutions/tree/main/json_parser/pyccjsonparser